# How to access filepath of a selected file, outside of a button?

Tags: java

I was creating a Music Player, and used JFileChooser to get the filepath of the selected track by user. And my main objective is to use the Filepath to play the track. I used Jaco MP3 jar, afterwards when JFileChooser gives filepath of the selected file, I'm trying to perfrom other music edit options like play-pause-stop. But idk why it's not accessing the filepath outside of the "Open" Button.

I've tried by changing all kind of If-Else Ladders, but that didn't work as well.

```
import jaco.mp3.player.MP3Player;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

class Demo implements ActionListener
{
    JFrame f1 = new JFrame("Music Player");

    JButton b1 = new JButton("Open");
    JButton b2 = new JButton("Play");
    JButton b3 = new JButton("Pause");
    JButton b4 = new JButton("Stop");

    JFileChooser fc;

    public String song="E:\\\\NCS Songs\\\\10convert.com_Marc-Madness-They-Are-Here-Bass-Boosted_bW8HHjJA8lQ.mp3";

    MP3Player mp3;

    String filepath;

    void proceed()
    {
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        b2.addActionListener(this);
        b3.addActionListener(this);
        b4.addActionListener(this);

        f1.add(b1);
        f1.add(b2);
        f1.add(b3);
        f1.add(b4);

        f1.setVisible(true);
        f1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        f1.setSize(400, 400);
        f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
       if(ae.getSource()==b1)
       {
        fc = new JFileChooser();    
        int i = fc.showOpenDialog(null);    

        if(i==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {    

           filepath = fc.getSelectedFile().getPath();

           mp3 = new MP3Player(new File(filepath));


        }

       }


         if(ae.getSource()==b2)
       {
          mp3 = new MP3Player(new File(filepath));
           mp3.play();
       }

       if(ae.getSource()==b3)
       {
             mp3 = new MP3Player(new File(filepath));
           mp3.pause();
       }

       if(ae.getSource()==b4)
       {
            mp3 = new MP3Player(new File(filepath));
           mp3.stop();
       }




    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
     new Demo().proceed();   
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not accessing the filepath"? Do you realize that `filepath` will be null until you've selected a file? Besides that, why are you reinitializing the mp3 player on each click of the other buttons?

Comment: @Thomas thanks you so much, when I removed extra initializations it did work. But I didn't understand what actually happen, after deleting those statements. Can you please explain me a bit ?

Comment: I can't tell what that `MP3Player` class is doing but you basically replaced the current mp3 player with a new instance. Since the previous instance still exists it might be still be playing the mp3 because all commands like `pause()` would operate on the new instance.

Comment: @Thomas oh now I get it, thank you so much once again man :)